# socket failed, errno=13 (Permission denied)

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, stress-testing

I'm using `stress-ng` on an an Ubuntu 20.04 vm.
When I try to use network related commands, like `sudo stress-ng --sock 1 --sock-ops 1 -v` it fail because of

> stress-ng-sock: socket failed, errno=13 (Permission denied)

I tried to run it with sudo. The socket port it tries to use is larger than 1024.

Would appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: And why is it a problem that a port above 1024 is used ?

Comment: In some configurations only root is allowed to bind to ports less than 1024.